# Multi Update statement using based off the following array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have a table named `sched` which I need to update as needed.

Currently I created a HTML output that outputs the current values of the `sched` table for a user to edit as they wish. I also have scripts in place to gather up these changes and send them via ajax/PHP to update said db tables.

I've already sent two separate arrays and used `array_combine()` to join them.

An example of the results sent to and combined via PHP:

```
            [locationID_1] => 4~West
            [instructorID_1] => 12~Kasey
            [roomID_1] => 7~Studio 1
            [classtypeID_1] => 9~Yoga
            [weekdayID_1] => 5~Friday
            [time_1] => 05:25
            [start_date_1] => 2014-09-01
            [end_date_1] => 2014-09-27
            [locationID_12] => 2~Oaks
            [roomID_12] => 2~Body Room
            [instructorID_12] => 3~Susan
            [classtypeID_12] => 13~Fitness
            [weekdayID_12] => 2~Tuesday
            [time_12] => 05:25
            [start_date_12] => 2014-09-03
            [end_date_12] => 2014-09-28
```

So for the last key value pair - the column names could be thought of as the first portion of each key (for the last entry):

```
UPDATE sched SET
end_date=2014-09-28
WHERE schedID=12
```

So to give a bit more about the example, the numbers within the [] brackets designate the id of the row of the table to be updated (12, sched).

The bit with it separated by the underscore is the name of the column (end_date).

The value assigned to each key is pieced with its own id retrieved from within its own db table prior to the ajax post.

My question is how best to UPDATE any number of rows within a targeted db table using the described approach.

I know there are many security issues with revealing this much db info in your javascript etc but this is more of a project for fun and learning (specially since im teaching this to myself).

Be kind, but informative - I'm hear to learn and progress.

Thanks
D

Comment: why did you combine? should have been easier if this is a multi dimentional array

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understand you need to create dynamic update statements. Then why not create a simple server side page and post data to that page and then use the below query

```
INSERT INTO sched({COLUMN_NAMES}) VALUES({COLUMN_VALUES}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than combining the arrays, I would suggest using a data structure more like the following. The data is cleaner and more easily accessible, from both a human, and algorithm point of view.

```
    $sched = array
    (
        1 => array
        (
            'locationID' => '4~West',
            'roomID' => '7~Studio 1',
            'instructorID' => '12~Kasey',
            'classtypeID' => '9~Yoga',
            'weekdayID' => '5~Friday',
            'time' => '05:25',
            'start_date' => '2014-09-01',
            'end_date' => '2014-09-27'
        ),
        12 => array
        (
            'locationID' => '2~Oaks',
            'roomID' => '2~Body Room',
            'instructorID' => '3~Susan',
            'classtypeID' => '13~Fitness',
            'weekdayID' => '2~Tuesday',
            'time' => '05:25',
            'start_date' => '2014-09-03',
            'end_date' => '2014-09-28'
        )
    );
```

And then looping over it like this:

```
    foreach ($sched as $id => $data)
    {
        $query = "UPDATE sched SET ";
        $sets = array();
        foreach ($data as $k => $v)
            $sets[] = "$k = '$v'";
        $query .= implode(', ', $sets) . " WHERE schedID = $id";

        // do something with query
    }
```